# How do I fetch a radom row from the database and display the same row to all the users in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any way to fetch a random row from the table and display the same row to all the users?
I know i can use the random() method to get the row but how do I display the same row to all the users.

**Here's my Controller:-**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::inRandomOrder;
use App\Nothingness;

class NothingnessController extends Controller
{
    public function randomQuestion()
    {
        $seed = Carbon::now()->toISOString();
            Nothingness::inRandomOrder($seed)->first();
            return view('home', compact('seed'));
    }
}
```

This is a new laravel project

Comment: you can use `random()` Eg: `Model::get()->random(5);`

Comment: @Vpa but the whole problem is how do i display the same row  to all the users

Comment: It's easy, you assign it to `variable` then you pass that `variable` to the `blade`

Comment: to display the same row to all users you have to use DB, so after getting random row you have to store some where this random choice to be available for all users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::inRandomOrder`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v7.22.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1916) method and provide it a seed.

> [This method is implemented in Eloquent models](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v7.22.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1731) via __call magic method.

The seed ensures that the results are ordered the same for the same seed.

The following is a query where everyone viewing at the same minute of day sees the same record.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use App\Nothingness;

class NothingnessController extends Controller
{
    public function randomQuestion()
    {
        $seed = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i');
        $randomNothing = Nothingness::inRandomOrder($seed)->first();
        return view('home', compact('randomNothing'));
    }
}
```

You could also have seed come from an external source.

Comment: Thanks Buddy let me try this and i'll accept the answer as soon as i am done with it

Comment: how do i provide it a seed?

Comment: I have extracted the seed value in its own variable to make it clear that the seed used in the example is the current timestamp

Comment: It shows there is something wrong with this `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::inRandomOrder` by showing this error syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM), expecting ';' or ','

Comment: Remove this `use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::inRandomOrder` statement. AFAIK, methods are not directly importable in PHP. Also import Carbon class.

Comment: It actually didn't work, when I logged in with 2 Different users and visited the same page there were different results

Comment: As it should be, the seed is a string representation  of the current time to the finest microsecond. If you require less precision, you could use seed representing the current minute of the day. There are common formats [documented here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting) but you et the idea